# Migrate property of objects to one list object

Tags: c#, linq

I have collection of objects which has property with type of collection.
How can i quick migrate objects property to  the one of collection object with help Linq.

```
Class obj 
{
    list<int> aa;
    List<obj> b = new List<obj>() 
    {
        new obj()
        {
            aa = new List<int>(){1,2,3}
        },
        new obj()
        {
            aa = new List<int>(){4,5,6}
        }
    }
}
```

i need to migrate all properties name **"aa"** of objects collection to one collection.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Use LINQ and [SelectMany](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534336(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
var result = b.SelectMany(o=>o.aa).ToList();
```

Comment: Thank u for a quick answer.